# PRISM, Unity,EventAggregator, ShellViewModel: Constructor is called twice

Tags: unity-container, viewmodel, prism

the reason of my issue is:
I'm tyring to avoid the EventAggregator-Pattern, because I think it makes code hard to understand and to debug.

Instead of using EventAggregator I tried to create a ShellViewModel and inject two ViewModels which should be wired to together for some reason:

```
public ShellViewModel(DocumentViewModel documentViewModel, ToolsViewModel toolsViewModel)
    {
      ...
    }
```

The problem I'm facing now is, that the documentViewModel and the toolsViewModel is created twice:

in my Bootstrapper:

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>(); //this implicitly calls the ctors of my viewmodels
    }
```

and in my module:

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        //This calls create the ViewModels again
        regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("ToolRegion", typeof(Views.ToolsView));
        regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(Views.DocumentView));
    }
```

How can I avoid, that the constructors are called twice?
If that is the wrong idea, how do I connect events of viewmodels in the same module?

**Edit (Solved):**

```
public ShellViewModel(IDocumentViewModel documentViewModel, IToolsViewModel toolsViewModel)
    {
      ...
    }
```

and

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
 {
   base.ConfigureContainer();
   RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof (IToolsViewModel), typeof (ToolsViewModel), true);
   RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IDocumentViewModel), typeof(DocumentViewModel), true);
 }
```

did the trick. It's neccessary to create an interface of the viewmodels and register the interface. Otherwise Unity will always create a new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ShellViewModel(IDocumentViewModel documentViewModel, IToolsViewModel toolsViewModel)
    {
      ...
    }
```

and

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
 {
   base.ConfigureContainer();
   RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof (IToolsViewModel), typeof (ToolsViewModel), true);
   RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IDocumentViewModel), typeof(DocumentViewModel), true);
 }
```

did the trick. It's neccessary to create an interface of the viewmodels and register the interface. Otherwise Unity will always create a new instance.

Comment: Not really. You can register a class, rather than an interface. The key difference between your two versions is the one that works for you is `RegisterTypeIfMissing`, rather than just `RegisterType`. If you want just a single instance of a particular class then you can also register it with a controlled lifetime, like this: `this.Container.RegisterType<ToolsView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());`

Comment: I have tried this.Container.RegisterType<ToolsView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());  at first without success. Constructor was still called twice.

Comment: In your bootstrapper, try adding `this.Container.Resolve<ToolsView>();` in addition to the `RegisterType`. This is the pattern I use when I want a single instance of a class that is imported into a number of different classes.